# How can I avoid Runtime error while implementing Heap Data Structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

I'm trying to solve a heap data structure problem using python in HackerRank.
I implemented it in two ways

**The First One**

```
from heapq import heappush,heappop

heap = []
deleted_nodes = []
num_of_entries = int(input())

for i in range(num_of_entries):

    line = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
    if line[0] == 1:
        heappush(heap,line[1])
    elif line[0] == 2:
        if heap[0] == line[1]:
            heappop(heap)
        else:
            heappush(deleted_nodes,line[1])

    elif line[0] == 3:
        check = bool(deleted_nodes)
        while check:
            if deleted_nodes[0] == heap[0]:
                heappop(heap)
                heappop(deleted_nodes)
                check = bool(deleted_nodes)
            else:
                check = False
                print(heap[0])
```

**The Second One**

```
from heapq import heappush,heappop


class Heap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.heap = []
        self.deleted_nodes = []

    def delete(self,value):
        if self.heap[0] == value:
            heappop(self.heap)
        else:
            heappush(self.deleted_nodes,value)

    def get_min(self):
        check = bool(self.deleted_nodes)
        while check:
            if self.deleted_nodes[0] == self.heap[0]:
                heappop(self.heap)
                heappop(self.deleted_nodes)
                check = bool(self.deleted_nodes)
            else:
                check = False
        print(self.heap[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":

    heap = Heap()
    num_of_entries = int(input())

    for i in range(num_of_entries):

        line = input().strip().split(' ')
        line = list(map(int,line))
        if line[0] == 1:
            heappush(heap.heap,line[1])

        elif line[0] == 2:
            heap.delete(line[1])

        elif line[0] == 3:
            heap.get_min()
```

**The First One** passed all test cases **successfully.**

**The Second one** passed more than **half** of the test cases and the remaining part kept getting **Runtime Error**

I can't really figure out why this is happening.

**PS:** Most of the failed test cases contain over **10000 values**.

Comment: Have you run the program yourself with the failing test case, and watched it fail? Seems like that should be the first thing you do. Then you can see *where* it fails, and what the specific runtime error is. If you don't have access to the failing test case, then create one yourself.

Comment: it seems that talking inputs with input() will cause a Run Time Error. Maybe I should start optimizing my code in the future with stdin instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks Like I should have taken the inputs through

```
stdin.readlines()
```

I replaced couple lines and it did pass all the test cases.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    heap = Heap()
    lines = stdin.readlines()
    for line in lines[1:]:
        line = line.split()
        line = list(map(int,line))
        if line[0] == 1:
            heappush(heap.heap,line[1])
        elif line[0] == 2:
            heap.delete(line[1])
        elif line[0] == 3:
            heap.get_min()
```